# Crash dump stack trace IIS7 + windows 2008 (64)

Tags: .net, iis-7

I have an AppPool which keeps crashing, initially with the below errors in the System event log:

A process serving application pool 'X' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was 'Y'. The data field contains the error number.

And after a few of those, the AppPool is stopped and the below error is in the System event log:

Application pool 'X' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

I've downloaded and installed v1.2 of Debug Diagnostic tools, and setup a Crash Rule for all IIS related processes but nothing is logging. I have read that this only works for apps running in 32 bit mode?

What other options do I have to find out the cause of this app crash?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ADPlus](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350) works with 64bit processes

Comment: Thanks. I've run the CMD "adplus -crash -pn w3wp.exe -o c:\temp"  (from the location C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64) for anyone interested). I'll see how this goes.

Comment: Yep, that's dumping out plenty of log data. Just got to interpret it now... (I've got WinDbg). Any tips on that would be appreciated too :)

Comment: You may need SOSEX for WinDbg to understand .NET code, although it may be included. [This SO topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946685/good-tutorial-for-windbg) is helpful, as is [this nice ASP.NET/WinDbg walkthrough by Tess Ferrandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/02/03/net-memory-leak-to-dispose-or-not-to-dispose-that-s-the-1-gb-question.aspx).