# Visual Studio 2012 Release only error

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, release

There are a number of errors going on here but I'm sure they are all linked, so first off I'm getting Access violation reading location exceptions at locations (generally near 0x00000000)
but I only get these exceptions in release and not in debug, even if i setup debugging to do so. Also I found where the error happens but when I step over that it goes in to a complete unrelated function that is not called in the line or in any of the functions in that line of code. But when similar code is called it still goes to this unrelated function but doesn't fail. This all only happens in release versions. I know which piece of code is causing the error as if I comment it out its all fine. Also in the watch window in release all the numbers are wrong most of the time, which has never been a problem but it could help also a added some code to it to output the values of variables to a file and the variables are all fine, the pointers are sensible, but when the exception happens it always says their 0x00000020 but when I look at the log they are fine. This is in 32 bit , but on 64 bit windows 7 in c++. Please any help would be good!

Comment: If you access an array using somthing like `a[8]` (if sizeof(a[0]) == 4) and `a` was `NULL` then you would get a Access violation at 0x00000020. Look for variables not getting assigned.

Comment: Thanks but no its something different as it seems to act randomly also in terms of the values of the variables everything is fine and then it just throws the exception, the main problem is that the code is so long 20000 lines and the error seems like something at the core parts of the code, but what I need is a way to approach the error. The code acts like I'm calling a non static function of a class that the pointer to is null.

Comment: Still sounds like a race condition to me, two threads touching one variable. either it is read before it set, or set then then reset to null before it gets read.

Comment: Again no I changed the code a little so that it all ran on one thread and I still get the error, anyway that section of code and memory only really involves one thread so it couldn't really be that.

Comment: Release build problems are hard to debug.  Start by disabling the optimizer so you'll have less trouble getting decent info from the debugger.  Project + Properties, C/C++, Optimization, Optimization = Disabled.

Comment: You can also create a PDB file with debug symbols, even in release builds.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's debugger will cause the program to use a debug heap that can hide uninitialized memory if you use the option "Start with Debugging" to start your program, in release or debug. You can try to run your program built in the Debug configuration without the debugger attached, and then use the Attach to Process... option in the debug menu to attach to your executable.

If this doesn't help, I recommend using [windbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx) to debug your program. For help getting started with windbg, take a look at the answers on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946685/good-tutorial-for-windbg).

Once windbg is configured and symbol paths are set up, you can use the "!analyze -v" option once the program crashes to get a lot of information about the crash automatically.

Comment: I found that if I run release without debugging it runs fine, no errors, I normal just run release with debugging, so I didn't notice but still why wouldn't it work with debugging in release mode.