# !threads command in WinDBG

Tags: debugging, windbg, remote-debugging

Hi I'm trying to debug a managed dll using windbg.

I have used the !threads command and see that I have 28 threads running but I dont understand the rest of the output as its the first time I have used WinDBG.

Can someone explain the meaning of the columns from the output of the **!threads** command?

```
                            PreEmptive   GC Alloc                   Lock
ID  OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC           Context           Domain   Count APT Exception
1   4e10 004e73b8      a020 Enabled      00000000:00000000 004e1388 0     MTA (Finalizer)    
2   38a0 004f3980      b220 Enabled      019a70ac:019a8fb0 004e1388 0     MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
```

Comment: You could probably look at this answer for windbg tutorial. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946685/good-tutorial-for-windbg. IMO it would be much easier for you to read.

Comment: This link was useful for me: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/08/10/managed-debugging-with-windbg-threads-part-1.aspx