# Can "DbgCommand()" also get the hyperlinked results?

Tags: python, windbg, dump, pykd

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185982/windbg-scripting-assigning-the-result-of-a-command-to-a-variable), I've tried to get a Windbg script working, but maybe I could solve my issue using PYKD anyway. My problem is the following:

I Launch the command `~* k`, and I get following response (as in the mentioned question, I like to emphasize the hyperlinks, hence the image instead of simple text):

[image: Windbg command result, containing hyperlinks]

I would like to simulate a mouse-click on the line, containing `CServiceModule::Run`. When I hover over the corresponding hyperlink `02`, I see following Windbg command:

```
dx Debugger.Sessions[0].Processes[4416].Threads[4436].Stack.Frames[2].SwitchTo();dv /t /v
```

Until now, I've tried re-creating this command myself, but now I realise that, if I can just get that command from the response itself, my problem is solved.

As far as I know, the PYKD `DbgCommand()` only gives the text part of the response (so, not the information under the hyperlink).

Is there any way to get this hyperlink from the `DbgCommand()` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know frame number, you can switch frame with pykd.setFrame command.
But you should remember, pykd does not support inline function frame. So a number of a frame can be different from windbg output. You can disable inline function with command 'inline 0'

The pykd script can look like that:

```
frames = getStack()
for frameNumber in xrange( len(frames) ):
    if "ServiceModule::Run" in findSymbol(frames[frameNumber].ip):
          setFrame(frameNumber)
          dprintln("frame switched")
```

**Extra edit for readability**
As mentioned in following comment, an issue has been raised to PYKD, named "[dbgCommand doesnt support DML command output](https://githomelab.ru/pykd/pykd/issues/7)": in other words: currently DML is not yet supported by PYKD `DbgCommand()`.

Comment: 1) there is an issue about DML support for dbgCommand:
https://githomelab.ru/pykd/pykd/issues/7
2) it is not consider to be important
3) I don't recommend to use dbgCommand. Many things can be achieved by pykd API. I've tried to show it in the above sample

Answer (score 0):

result of kb

```
0:000> kb
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 000bf618 76fa0e00 7ffdf000 7ffda000 76ff714c ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c
01 000bf778 76f860a7 000bf7ec 76f20000 76c245cb ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x11a9
02 000bf7c8 76f83659 000bf7ec 76f20000 00000000 ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0x78
03 000bf7d8 00000000 000bf7ec 76f20000 00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x10
```

when i click on the dml link 02 i get

```
0:000> dx Debugger.Sessions[0].Processes[2684].Threads[3736].Stack.Frames[2].SwitchTo();dv /t /v
Debugger.Sessions[0].Processes[2684].Threads[3736].Stack.Frames[2].SwitchTo()
Unable to enumerate locals, Win32 error 0n87
Private symbols (symbols.pri) are required for locals.
Type ".hh dbgerr005" for details.
```

as i emphasized in my earlier answers the same can be achieved by

**dx @$curstack.Frames[2].SwitchTo();dv /v /t**

typing this is exactly equivalent to clicking the 02 link

```
0:000> dx @$curstack.Frames[2].SwitchTo();dv /v /t
@$curstack.Frames[2].SwitchTo()
Unable to enumerate locals, Win32 error 0n87
Private symbols (symbols.pri) are required for locals.
Type ".hh dbgerr005" for details.
```

this will be meaningful only if you are debugging with source available 
here is an example of stack and frame 2 with source

i am using kbL to hide my src line info on the stacktrace 
and then clicked frame no 2 DML link 
and then type the command  as you can see it print the same info like you click

now if you say i need to see the "RUN" string not use the number 2 
you should write a script to text parse each line as i showed you in my earlier answer to the thread you linked

```
0:000> kbL
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 (Inline) -------- -------- -------- -------- mfctest!CThreadLocal<_AFX_THREAD_STATE>::GetData
01 0025fe48 012fbc2f 015bf7a8 012fd4bd ffffffff mfctest!AfxGetThreadState
02 0025fe64 0151979e 00000000 015c6360 7ffdb000 mfctest!CWinThread::Run+0xf
03 0025fe7c 014c17d5 012e0000 00000000 00322d3e mfctest!AfxWinMain+0x93
04 (Inline) -------- -------- -------- -------- mfctest!invoke_main+0x1a
05 0025fec8 76e8ed6c 7ffdb000 0025ff14 76f837eb mfctest!__scrt_common_main_seh+0xf8
06 0025fed4 76f837eb 7ffdb000 76b22d01 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
07 0025ff14 76f837be 014c1892 7ffdb000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
08 0025ff2c 00000000 014c1892 7ffdb000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


clicking link with number 2
0:000> dx Debugger.Sessions[0].Processes[620].Threads[2228].Stack.Frames[2].SwitchTo();dv /t /v
Debugger.Sessions[0].Processes[620].Threads[2228].Stack.Frames[2].SwitchTo()
@ebx              class CWinThread * this = 0x015bf7a8 {h=0xfffffffe proc={...}}
<unavailable>     long lIdleCount = <value unavailable>
@eax              class _AFX_THREAD_STATE * pState = 0x0153b820
<unavailable>     int bIdle = <value unavailable>


using command (NOT CLICKING BUT TYPING THIS )
0:000> dx @$curstack.Frames[2].SwitchTo();dv /v /t
@$curstack.Frames[2].SwitchTo()
@ebx              class CWinThread * this = 0x015bf7a8 {h=0xfffffffe proc={...}}
<unavailable>     long lIdleCount = <value unavailable>
@eax              class _AFX_THREAD_STATE * pState = 0x0153b820
<unavailable>     int bIdle = <value unavailable>
```