# IIS worker process is showing queue for one of the app pool

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, garbage-collection, iis-8.5

I have a ASP.NET WEB API application hosted on IIS. IIS is queuing request.  The server is not very busy and I still get queuing.  So I am trying to find out the reasons IIS would queue requests.  The main reason (only) I have heard is if the max threads is reached.  I suspect it is something I am doing in my application but I have no idea what that could be.  Does anyone know IIS well enough to tell me the reasons requests get put into the request queue or point me in the proper direction?

Is there any way to get hold of current active threads in IIS or list of blocked threads in IIS. is there any tool that can help us with this. I checked the event viewer and it was clean.

Comment: There is a tool called windbg, that it could be used to get a  memory dumb of your live application that you could later on analyse  and find out what is going on. However, you have to invest some time to learn the very basics of this tool. Here you will find an answer with useful material to getting started, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946685/good-tutorial-for-windbg.

Comment: @Christos: I do have the memory dump and started to look into dump using windbg and found it very challenging to understand it. I was hoping or a better tool. I will continue to investigate.

Comment: yeap, unfortunately it has some steep learning curve but your investment would pay off definitely. Good luck !

Comment: No one expects you to locate the culprit of hang scenarios with a tool quickly, as there are tons of typical causes and patterns. If possible, find someone locally to help or open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com That's far beyond ordinary tools and experience level.

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could try to use performance monitor to see the queue up is happened on which part. HTTP Service Request Queues  or  Request in Application Queue.  Details about how to use it , you could refer to this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd744567(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Besides, I suggest you could check the work process's request url to find out which api function caused queue up and check its codes to make sure it works well without taking so long time to handle request