# How to escape quotation marks in WinDbg's startup command line opening a dump

Tags: command-line-arguments, windbg

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655168/how-do-i-make-a-cmdtree-window-dock-at-startup-in-windbg), I'm trying to set up a `.dmp` shell command in the Registry using the `-c "..."` switch to execute commands whenever I open a dump file.

While this works for any commands not using quotation marks, I'd now like to use a command which needs quotation marks. How can I escape the quotation marks to that they are not seen as the end of the `-c "..."` switch?

I tried:

- escaping with a backslash `\"`
- escaping by doubling the quotation marks `""`

Details are :

Registry key: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windbg.DumpFile.1\shell\WinDbgStartup\command`

(Default) value (working): `"C:\path to\windbg.exe" -z "%1" -Q -c ".echo Welcome"`

(Default) value (broken): `"C:\path to\windbg.exe" -z "%1" -Q -c ".echo Wel""come"`

`-z` is for opening a dump file, `-Q` is for quiet workspaces, at `-c` I can enter commands and I want to include quatation marks.

Error message: `The command line arguments cannot specify more than one kind of debugging to start`

WinDbg Version: `6.2.9200.16384 X86`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `^"` ? `^` escapes most characters in `cmd`

---

(On investigation)

Quote from[WinDbg Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
-c " command "

    Specifies the initial debugger command to run at start-up. This command must be 
    enclosed in quotation marks. Multiple commands can be separated with semicolons. 
    (If you have a long command list, it may be easier to put them in a script and 
    then use the -c option with the $<, $><, $><, $$>< (Run Script File) command.)

    If you are starting a debugging client, this command must be intended for the 
    debugging server. Client-specific commands, such as .lsrcpath, are not allowed.
```

And clicking on the `$...` hyperlink further explains these options.

Seems that you actually want to include the <kbd>"</kbd> in your `echo`. Frankly, I've no idea - but what I'd try would be `-c ".echo Wel^"come"`

and if that doesn't work, I'd go off to the `$-option` gobbledegook. No-one (sane) ever claimed that every possibility had been considered in constructing these facilities...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately it does not work with `^"` either.

Comment: Hmm - some hint of the command you wish to execute may be useful.

Comment: Ok, I have added my registry details