# Can I automate Windbg to attach to a process and set breakpoints?

Tags: windbg

I am debugging a windows process that crashes if the execution stops for even a few milliseconds. (I don't know how many exactly, but it is definitely less than the time taken by my reflexes to resume the process.)

I know I can launch a windbg session via the command prompt by typing in `windbg -p PID` which brings up the GUI. But can I then further pass it windbg commands via the command prompt, such as `bm *foo!bar* ".frame;gc";g"`.

Because If I can pass it these commands I can write these down in a `.bat` file and just run it. There would at least be no delay due to entering (or even copy-pasting) the commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `-c` parameter to pass them:

```
windbg -p PID -c "bm *foo!bar* .frame;gc;g"
```

According to the help (found by running `windbg /?`):

> -c "command"
>
> Specifies the initial debugger command to run at start-up. This command must be enclosed in quotation marks. Multiple commands can be separated with semicolons. (If you have a long command list, it may be easier to put them in a script and then use the -c option with the $<, $><, $><, $$>< (Run Script File) command.)
>
> If you are starting a debugging client, this command must be intended for the debugging server. Client-specific commands, such as .lsrcpath, are not allowed.

You may need to play around with the quotes...

**Edit:** Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20990728/1698557), you might be better off putting the commands into a script file to deal with the quotes:

`script.txt` (I think this is what you want):

```
bm *foo!bar* ".frame;gc"
g
```

Then in your batch file:

```
windbg -p PID -c "$<full_path_to_script_txt"
```

Comment: where to put the script.txt file because the error says that windbg is unable to find it.

Comment: Anywhere, as long as the directory it is in is the working directory when you start Windbg.

Comment: Keeping it in the same directory as windbg.exe would do it then?

Comment: The command I am typing in is: `windbg -p 19684 -c "$$<script.txt"` and the corresponding result is [this](http://prntscr.com/4wg25k). NOTE: This is inside windbg command window, the said process has been attached but the script file did not execute.

Comment: And for a single `$`, that is, `windbg -p 19684 -c "$<script.txt"` the result is [this](http://prntscr.com/4wg3o6). Again the process has been attached but the script did not execute.

Comment: Use a single `$`, and put `script.txt` in the [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

Comment: See edits, I don't know how to be clearer without completely describing what a working directory is.

Comment: Got it to work. Needed to provide it the full directory to the script.txt file, no quotes, no escaping the backward slash.