# How to ensure a dump file is written by C++ application in case of unhandled exception

Tags: c++, windows, windbg, crash-dumps

How to ensure a dump file is written by C++ application in case of exception which is not handled.

For example if division by zero is not handled then how do ensure Dump is written.

Also It will be great to have windbg tutorial I tried searching on but NOT a good one found .

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're looking for an external way to get those dumps created (after all, you're asking about exceptions that are *not handled*).

In Vista and above, the mechanism you're looking for is called Windows Error Reporting - WER. You can [configure it to create dumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) upon crash, and place them at a certain location. Prior to Vista, you could do that using [drwtsn32.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308538). You can also run your program using [ADPlus](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350), which will create a dump as soon as the process crashes, without the need for any system-wide configuration.

If you'd like to create a dump from the program itself, you can use [MiniDumpWriteDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , but that's less advisable. When in an unclear state, it's better to let some other process take the snapshot of yours.

As for WinDbg, there's really a ton of information on the web. I guess you can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734272/how-to-use-windbg-to-analyze-the-crash-dump-for-vc-application), but you should ask specific questions if you have specific problems.